# how to make the image inside the container with around shape

Tags: image, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

How do I place the image inside the container in the left of the container with the shape around. Like in this image

[image: image of 2 cards]

Here is my existing code.

```
 Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(40)),
                  boxShadow: <BoxShadow>[
                    BoxShadow(
                        color: Colors.black38,
                        offset: Offset(2, 4),
                        blurRadius: 5,
                        spreadRadius: 2)
                  ],
                  gradient: LinearGradient(
                      begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
                      end: Alignment.centerRight,
                      colors: [Color(0xfff3f3f4), Color(0xfff3f3f4)]
                  )
              ),
              width: double.infinity,
              height: 130,
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    width: double.infinity,
                    height: 130,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        // borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(30)),
                    image: DecorationImage(
                    image: AssetImage('images/veg.jpg'),
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,)),

                  ),
                  SizedBox(width: 30,),
                  Text("Lunch", style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      color: Colors.black,
                      fontSize: 20),),
                ],),
            ),
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Container(
          height: 90,
          width: double.infinity,
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5, horizontal: 5),
          margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: white,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
            boxShadow: [
              BoxShadow(
                  color: Color(0x29000000),
                  offset: Offset(0, 0),
                  blurRadius: 8,
                  spreadRadius: 0)
            ],
          ),
          child: Row(
            children: [
              CircleAvatar(
                child: Image.network(
                  "https://i.stack.imgur.com/4UykF.png",
                  height: 70,
                  width: 70,
                ),
              ),
              Text(
                Localization.of(context).addCard,
              )
            ],
          ),
        )
```

[image]